# Specifying runtime play application configuration built with "dist"

Tags: playframework

I am building universally distributable play application using the "dist" command. This works fine however it was still using the dev application configuration once deployed. I thought that, because play created the following file,

`/somewhere/myapp/conf/application.conf`

it would automagically use it. This appears not to be the case. How can I tell play to pick up run time changes to the application.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The play framework does not load the `myapp/conf/application.conf` unless you tell it to by using the `-Dconfig.file` system property. Thus, launching my app with

`/somewhere/myapp/bin/myapp -Dconfig.file=/somewhere/myapp/conf/application.conf`

did the trick and it picked up the correct configuration.